# Does FirebaseUI for firestore needs ViewModel? in Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, viewmodel, firebaseui

I have an small question about FirebaseUI

Does FirebaseUI for firestore needs ViewModel? or firebase automatically handles this for us?
although firebaseUi provides paging and recyclerviewadapter built it functions and class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In simple situation :**
If your firebase UI is in one Activity and only being used for login then
to be precise the answer is **NO**. Because most of the *Data* handling stuff is being done by the Firebase API so that the authentication or authorization will be done. *But keep in mind that Device Rotaion will reset the Firebase UI* .

**In Complex Android app development :**
And the answer is **YES** because **Viewmodel** is really nedded for firebase UI to communicate with other components in android like *fragments* & activities which are lifecycle aware. SO that he *data* returned by the UI will be retained.

Comment: while using navigation component with FirebaseUI does i need to add ViewModel class in my project?

Comment: YES you do need to add viewModel to your project.